# Problema com window.open() JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, table, funções

Tenho uma tabela composta por 3 colunas: link, status, ação.

Na coluna ação, eu tenho 2 links que servirão como "botões": VER & DESCARTAR
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Essa tabela tem em media +100 linhas...***

Eu preciso que quando o usuário clique em VER, seja pego o valor da coluna "Link" na linha respectiva...para que seja montado um link onde ocorrerá um redirecionamento para uma página em uma nova aba.

**Exemplo lógico:**

String valor = pega o valor da coluna link na linha respectiva
String link = "http://site"+valor

---

**O que eu já fiz:**

Eu estou utilizando a seguinte função

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable td').click(function() {
        posicao = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
        link = $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text();

        $(this).attr('title', link);

        window.open("http://www.webmotors.com.br"+link);
    });
});
</script>
```

Essa função pega o valor da coluna link quando eu clico na linha (tr) da tabela...eu queria pegar o valor só quando clicasse em VER, mas não consegui fazer desse jeito, se alguém souber um jeito para fazer isso ficarei grato.

**O problema:**

Quando executa o window.open(site)
A página que gera em uma nova aba vem com um "%20" entre o site e o link que tenho no valor da tabela...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse %20 impede em abrir a página...se eu tirar ele na mão a página abre... 
Não entendi porque ele aparece aí no meio...preciso tirar ele fora.

A parte que monta o link é:

```
window.open("http://www.webmotors.com.br"+link);
```

Preciso de ajuda com isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%20` é o ASCII Encode equivalente ao **espaço**, ou seja, um simples `' '` *(ignora aspas)*.

Provavelmente seu link possui um espaço no começo, utilize o método `.trim()` para remover espaços indesejados no começo e final.

Exemplo:

```
window.open("http://www.webmotors.com.br"+link.trim());
```

Comment: muito obrigado, o comando .trim() resolveu o problema, mais uma que aprendi...valeu

Answer (score 2):

A solução do Maicon está correta, mas eu não acho que é uma boa ideia “reciclar” pedaços da UI pra usar em redirecionamentos, AJAX, etc. porque acontecem esses tipos de problemas que você encontrou.

O que você pode fazer é colocar um atributo a mais no seu `<tr>`, algo tipo

```
<tr data-link="/comprar/toyota/…">…</tr>
```

E aí você acessaria o link via

```
var link = $(this).parents('tr').data('link');
```

(Considere, inclusive, colocar o `http://www.webmotors.com.br` pra dentro do `data-link` também; no dia que você quiser ter mais de um site, você só precisa mexer em um lugar.)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar desse jeito que vc falou também...valeu

Answer (score -1):

use `window.location.href`, e coloca uma barra depois do link, `

```
window.location.href("http://www.webmotors.com.br/"+link);
```

Comment: então o window.location.href não abre a page em uma nova aba como eu preciso...ainda assim eu coloquei ele no código mas continua vindo o %20 e não abre corretamente.